# right alignment for a button in ion-col

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have this grid in my Ionic 2 application. Is there any ionic-specific attribute to make the button shown on the right side of the column (row)?

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>col 1</ion-col>
    <ion-col>col 2</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button>My button</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your case you can add the attribute `float-right` like so:

```
<button ion-button float-right>My button</button>
```

**float-{modifier}**
The [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#element-placement) says you can add the attribute `float-{modifier}` to position an element inside its container.

`{modifier}` can be any of the following:
`right`: The element will float on the right side of its container.
`left`:  The element will float on the left side of its container.
`start`: The same as `float-left` if direction is left-to-right and float-right if direction is right-to-left.
`end`:   The same as float-right if direction is left-to-right and float-left if direction is right-to-left.

Example:

```
<div>
    <button ion-button float-right>My button</button>
</div>
```

**item-{modifier}**
To position an element inside an `ion-item` the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/) says you can use `item-{modifier}`.

Where `{modifier}` can be any of the following:
`start`: Placed to the left of all other elements, outside of the inner item.
`end`: Placed to the right of all other elements, inside of the inner item, outside of the input wrapper.
`content`: Placed to the right of any ion-label, inside of the input wrapper.

Example:

```
<ion-item>
    <button ion-button item-end>My button</button>
</ion-item>
```

**Deprecation**
According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/rtl-support/) these names are deprecated:

`item-right` & `item-left`

The new names are :

- `item-start` & `item-end`
- `padding-start` & `padding-end`
- `margin-start` & `margin-end`
- `text-start` & `text-end`
- `start` and `end` for FABs

Comment: It worked fine. I was trying item-right, but it wasn't working. Do you know the difference?

Comment: I dont know if `item-right` is used at all anymore, my guess is that `float-right` is its substitute. Cant find anything about ´item-right´ in the docs.

Comment: `item-right` just works to place elements inside of an `ion-item`. So if you want to place a button inside of an item, or if you want to place the icon of a radio item to the right, you can always use `ion-item`. But it wont work outside of an `ion-item`. Btw thanks @robbannn for the `float-right` attribute, I wasn't aware of it at all :)

Comment: Youre welcome! I have seen `item-right` in some examples that I have encountered, but I cant find anything about it in the documentation. For horizontal positioning inside an `ion-item` I have found `item-end`, `item-start` and `item-content`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I can't find them anymore in the docs. I guess this is part of the new RTL support feature of ionic, where makes way more sense to use _start_ and _end_ instead of _absolute words_ like _left_ and _right_ :/

Comment: @IonicMan, are you developing in Ionic 2 or 3? Things may have changed in Ionic 4 or 5.

Comment: many things have changed in ionic 4 and 5, yeah. im using ionic 5

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution didnt work for me. I think it is relevant to ionic v3 and not the current. I solved my problem like this:

page.html:

```
<div class="test">
    <ion-button>My button</ion-button>
</div>
```

page.scss:

```
.test {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ionic 6.18.2 where this works for me:

```
<ion-button class="ion-float-right">Button Text</ion-button>
```